# How to install Java on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: java, java-11, ubuntu-server

I need to install Oracle JDK 11 on Ubuntu Server 18.04. I have seen many tutorials but all of those point that I need to download this repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

But it is not working. This is what I get:

[image: Error Linuxuprising repo]

Also, I need to install Open JDK 14 in the same Ubuntu machine, but I'm unable to find working instructions.

Does somebody have any hints on these issues?

Comment: Did you tried with `update-alternatives`?

Comment: Yep. But I got an error when I run the Linuxuprising command above.

Comment: There should be a package named `openjdk-11-jdk-headless`

Comment: Well, I saw how to install OpenJdk 11, but I need Oracle JDK and I feel kinda confused about that

Comment: Check this link for how to install java in Ubuntu https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try to the install dependencies to add a repository, Hope this will be my missing step.

Comment: Check this guide https://dzone.com/articles/installing-openjdk-11-on-ubuntu-1804-for-real . This guide mostly related to your question . This is for ubuntu desktop version means that it will also the same setup for ubuntu server 18.04.

Comment: Did you know about the new [Oracle license rules](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to askubuntu.com

Comment: Are you sure you need the Oracle JDK? If you have a support contract with Oracle, you could ask Oracle how to install their JDK

Comment: Yes, it is a requirement to have those two versions of JDK

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be possible to just type "sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk" or "sudo apt-get install openjdk-14-jdk"

This should Help you with all the OpenJDK stuff
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/OpenJDK/

Comment: When I execute sudo apt-get install openjdk-14-jdk It launches the permission window for Oracle JDK 14. What I'm doing wrong?